# flutter how to catch error google sign in

Tags: flutter, dart

```
Future<UserCredential> signInWithGoogle() async {
// Trigger the authentication flow
final GoogleSignInAccount googleUser = await GoogleSignIn().signIn();

// Obtain the auth details from the request
final GoogleSignInAuthentication googleAuth =
    await googleUser.authentication;

// Create a new credential
final GoogleAuthCredential credential = GoogleAuthProvider.credential(
  accessToken: googleAuth.accessToken,
  idToken: googleAuth.idToken,
);

// Once signed in, return the UserCredential
return await FirebaseAuth.instance.signInWithCredential(credential);
```

}

Future signInWithFacebook() async {
// Trigger the sign-in flow

```
try {
  final AccessToken accessToken = await FacebookAuth.instance.login();

  // Create a credential from the access token
  final OAuthCredential credential = FacebookAuthProvider.credential(
    accessToken.token,
  );
  // Once signed in, return the UserCredential
  return await FirebaseAuth.instance.signInWithCredential(credential);
} on FacebookAuthException catch (e) {
  // handle the FacebookAuthException
} on FirebaseAuthException catch (e) {
  // handle the FirebaseAuthException
} finally {}
return null;
```

}

```
//pub.yaml
  google_sign_in: ^5.0.1
```

make the social login auth but I can't catch error google sign in.

I'm already Facebook sign in and apple sign in error catch but
I can't catch error on google sign in
please help me

Comment: What kind of exception is unhandled?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right now I'm also facing this issue. Your code is fine. Run your app in Release mode and everything will work fine as expected. It's very strange behavior.

this only occurs in Emulators, not in the real devices.

Answer (score 0):

If you make the return type of <UserCredential?> nullable, you'd be able to work with it.

```
  //this UserCredential?
    Future<UserCredential?> signInWithGoogle() async {
    // Trigger the authentication flow
    try {
      final GoogleSignInAccount? googleUser = await (GoogleSignIn().signIn());

      // Obtain the auth details from the request
      final GoogleSignInAuthentication googleAuth = await googleUser!.authentication;

      // Create a new credential
      final GoogleAuthCredential credential = GoogleAuthProvider.credential(
        accessToken: googleAuth.accessToken,
        idToken: googleAuth.idToken,
      ) as GoogleAuthCredential;

      // Once signed in, return the UserCredential

      return await FirebaseAuth.instance.signInWithCredential(credential);
    } catch (e) {
      print(e);
      return null ;
    }
  }
```